# Dictionary containing Arrays containing Dictionaries?

Tags: ios, swift

Code snippets:

This is from a struct called `Static`:

```
static var messages: Dictionary = [:]
```

This is inside a class function:

```
if Static.messages[sender] == nil{ //no message history, create array then append
    var messages: [NSMutableDictionary] = [message]
    Static.messages[sender] = messages
}
else{ //there is message history, so append
    (Static.messages[sender] as Array).append(message)
}
```

Error:

```
Immutable value of type 'Array<T>' only has mutating members named 'append'
```

I'm trying to make a Dictionary of conversations with each item being a person. Each array will be a list of messages. The messages are of type dictionary. Any idea why I'm getting this message?

Comment: what is `message`? Which line is the error on? Can you please post enough code that we can stick it in a playground to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Message is a dictionary. The error is on line `(Static.messages[sender] as Array).append(message)`. To reproduce the error, you're going to need access to my server to get the data, along with all the code.

Comment: Just grab the data that your server produces and hard code it into a variable in a playground file. You haven't posted enough details for me to help you. Please post more or else your question is likely to be closed. As for why you're getting the message, it's just because your syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're clear with the compiler about what your dictionary contains, you won't need the cast that is making this difficult. From what you've posted, the actual type of `Static.messages` will need to be something like `Dictionary<NSObject, Array<NSMutableDictionary>>`.

Your current attempt casts a dictionary value as an `Array` and then tries to append -- this fails because Swift treats the result of this kind of cast as immutable. What you need to do instead is to simply use optional chaining:

```
// instead of:
(Static.messages[sender] as Array).append(message)

// use:
Static.messages[sender]?.append(message)
```

Comment: Can I add `static var messages: Dictionary = [:]` is inside of a struct called Static.

Comment: I saw that - has this ever compiled, or are you stuck on this error? You need to give `Dictionary` instances key and value types when declaring them - that line won't work as is.

Comment: You could declare it like this: `static var messages: [NSObject: [NSMutableDictionary]] = [:]`

Comment: It has not compiled since I added this second snippet. However, after I changed the declaration to `static var messages: [NSObject: [NSMutableDictionary]] = [:]`, it now compiles. Thank-you